# How would you recreate this bass kick sound?

Tags: ableton, synthesis, bass, replication

How would you recreate this bass sounds?

I wonder how he can get that wavy effect.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

LFO! Low Frequency Oscillator. I don't know what synth you're using so I can't help you on the process of getting the LFO working with your bass sound. You will need to use the LFO on your cut-off filter, it can usually be synced with the tempo of the song.

Here is a really simple video that shows the effect of the LFO:

Listen to it at 2:20, you can hear the 'wavy' effect it creates.

Hope this helps!

Ad

Comment: Thanks for answering Ad. I use Massive generally. What kind of wave would you use for this sound? I'd start with a square with a low-pass filter and then add some LFO on the filter's cutoff. Do you think there's some glide in it too? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, had to get xmas and new year drinking out of the way haha! Sounds to me like its a subtle mix of two oscillators, one sine wave and one square wave (I could be wrong!), and yes it does sound like there is some glide but only a little. To recreate that actual sound will really just mean trial and error for the most part, but to get the wobbly sound is just automating that filter cut-off. Sorry I can't be of any more help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that, you can recreate this with any Massive "Bass" preset and playing notes around -2 or -3 octaves, and the waviness is caused by sidechain compression. Glide? Maybe, but i wouldn't say that so easily. More like an envelope with a long release.

(maybe you already got it "since january") ;)